# How to use sed to replace strings with categories?

Tags: shell-script, sed, replace

I have some categories and their values:

```
Category: Value:
1*4  15.934934
1*5*3            19.281281
1*8*10*2      78.20912
```

I would like to replace the categories by numbers that represent the categories.

For example:

1*4   has two numbers then it would be replaced by  2

1*5*3  has three numbers then it would be replaced by 3

1*8*10*2    has four numbers then it would be replaced by 4

I need to do the process for hundreds of files so it is very important to automate the process!

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`? there's a straightforward way in `awk` for example

Comment: How would you do in using awk? :)

Comment: Do a `gsub` of sequences of digits in `$1` and assign the result (number of successful substitutions) back to `$1` i.e. `$1 = gsub(/[0-9]+/,"",$1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `sed` has no concept of numbers, this is a bit laborious to do:

```
sed -E 's/^[0-9]+\*/1*/; s/^1\*[0-9]+/2/; s/^2\*[0-9]+/3/; s/^3\*[0-9]+/4/;' input
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [steeldriver's idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/375031/how-to-use-sed-to-replace-strings-with-categories#comment667125_375031), but counting stars:

```
awk '{ $1 = 1 + gsub(/\*/, "", $1); print; }' < input > output
```

When run on the sample input, it results in:

```
2 15.934934
3 19.281281
4 78.20912
```